# xdotool Up displaying extra characters

Tags: gnome, xdotool, gestures, xev

I'm trying to use xdotool to configure touchpad gestures on Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome.

This works fine:

```
xdotool key ctrl+alt+Down
```

However this:

```
xdotool key ctrl+alt+Up
```

does not change workspaces and instead seems to output some extra characters to the terminal.

[image: as seen in this screenshot]

I also attempted to use the serial values, and the keysym values output by the `xev` command and the behavior is identical.

Comment: Is this a Wayland session?

Comment: @DKBose I'm not on my machine, but it was my impression that 18.04 ships with `xorg` by default, and I have not changed it. I will confirm when I get home but I am on whatever is default for Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @DKBose I can confirm that I am on X11.

Comment: Okay! The reason I asked is that there *is* a Wayland option the user can choose at the time of logging in. `xdotool` works only partially in a Wayland session even with xwayland present :(

Comment: @DKBose Thanks for the help. I found a workaround that someone posted on the `xdotool` github page. It looks like its a known bug.

Answer (score 1):

I found some explanation to why this happens and somewhat of a workaround.

There are several issues on the `xdotool` github page that mention issues like this. Apparently it is caused by a misinterpretation of keyboard configuration due to the vast number of possible configurations that `xdotool` is not programmed to handle, or something like that.

There is somewhat of a workaround, and it has allowed me to program my gestures. The trick is to have `xdotool` type something directly after issuing the command, like this:

`xdotool key ctrl+alt+Up && xdotool type :`

The ":" is just an arbitrary character.

Doing so executes the workspace switch now! I'll leave this up in case anybody else stumbles upon this question with my same issue.